# Replacing numerical values into categorical values in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to substitute values in the following range but I don't understand why for the 2 first variables, the second substitution is not working but the third variable does. Any idea to fix it?

This is my code:

```
# Creating new variables:
df[, "icPM10"] <- df$PM10
df[, "icO3"] <- df$O3
df[, "RS_re"] <- df$RS

# Substitution

df$icPM10[df$icPM10 > 0 & df$icPM10 <= 45 ] <- "aceptable"
df$icPM10[df$icPM10 > 45 & df$icPM10 <= 180  ] <- "mejorable"

df$icO3[df$icO3 > 0 & df$icO3 <= 60 ] <- "aceptable"
df$icO3[df$icO3 > 60 & df$icO3 <= 170  ] <- "mejorable"


df$RS_re[df$RS_re > 0 & df$RS_re <= 100 ] <- "normal_baja"
df$RS_re[df$RS_re > 100 & df$RS_re <= 700  ] <- "normal_alta"
```

And this is the output (sample):

[image]

I did this kind of substitution in other datasets and had no problem. At first, I thought it could be because I transformed the column into a `char`, but it doesn't really matter.

Any help will be welcome!

Comment: Once you assign the 'acceptable' to the same column which was numeric, it converts to character class and thus the second condition which is on the same column woulnd't work.  You mayneed to create a new column and do the assign

Comment: So how is it possible that the `df$RS_re` works? I did with other datasets and I didn't have this type of issue.

Comment: Note that the comparison operator also works for character elements but it is alphabetic order.  So, it may sometimes returns correct by coincidence

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Could I also change the `char` column into a numeric with `as.numeric()` and then do the substitution? Thanks akrun (another time) :)

Comment: Better would be to create a temporary column or vector to change the values while keeping the original column not modified.  Once all the modifications are made, then assign the original column with the values from temporary column so that you don't have to do type conversions.  Also, the `as.numeric` converts any non-numeric values to `NA` (so it is not advissable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the first assignment, `icPM10` column is no longer numeric as it gets converted to `character` class and thus the second expression on the same column wouldn't work.  We may use `ifelse` or `case_when` (would be better as it can take multiple expressions)

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
      mutate(icPM10 = case_when(between(icPM10, 0, 45) ~ 'acetable',
                                between(icPM10, 45, 180) ~ 'mejorable',
                        TRUE ~ as.character(icPM10)))
```